# How to sort multiples value in directory by Python

Tags: python, file

I have 540 files in my directory. All files' data formats are given below:

*File input.txt*

```
class    confidence    Xmin        Ymin        Xmax           Ymax
7         0.3456900    89          8            39             53
6         0.0123457    2           1            23             43
```

*File result.txt*

```
class    confidence    Xmin        Ymin        Xmax           Ymax
6         0.0123457    2           1            23             43
7         0.3456900    89          8            39             53
```

I've solved this problem for reading a single file. Code is given below:

This is my single text file compare code. It's working. But I have 540 text files, and I want to sort files like this. How can I sort multiple files in my directory by the same process ? I need to make a specific file name for each file.

```
from collections import defaultdict 

maxima = defaultdict(int)

with open('F:\GGR\grnd.txt', 'r') as ifh:
    for line in ifh:
        key, value = line.rsplit(None, 1)
        value = int(value)
        if value > maxima[key]:
            maxima[key] = value

with open('output.txt', 'w') as ofh:
    for key in sorted(maxima):
        ofh.write('{} {}\n'.format(key, maxima[key]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) to find all files under your directory uncluding subdirs:

**Your code adapted:**

```
from collections import defaultdict 
import os

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r'F:\GGR'):  # this recurses into subdirectories as well
    for f in files:
        maxima = defaultdict(int)
        try:
            with open(os.path.join(root,f)) as ifh:
                for line in ifh:
                    key, value = line.rsplit(None, 1)
                    value = int(value)
                    if value > maxima[key]:
                        maxima[key] = value

            with open(os.path.join(root, f'{f}.out'), 'w') as ofh:
                for key in sorted(maxima):
                    ofh.write('{} {}\n'.format(key, maxima[key]))
        except ValueError:
            # if you have other files in your dir, you might get this error because they 
            # do not conform to the structure of your "needed" files - skip those
            print(f, "Error converting value to int:", value)
```

If you do not need to recurse into subdirs, use [os.listdir](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir)

**A better solution:**

Sort the files content directly using the *key* argument for `sorted` :

```
from collections import defaultdict 
import os

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r'./'):
    for f in files:
        print(f)
        maxima = defaultdict(int)
        try:
            with open(os.path.join(root,f)) as ifh, open(
                      os.path.join(root, f'{f}.out'), 'w') as ofh:
                # header
                ofh.write(next(ifh))  
                # data
                ofh.write( '\n'.join(sorted(ifh.readlines(), key = 
                                            lambda x: int(x.split()[-1])))) 
        except ValueError:
            print(f, "Error converting value to int:", ifh)
```